# Error setting up Raid 1 with mdadm at RaspberryPi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raid, mdadm

I was setting up a RAID 1 with mdadm at my RaspberryPi with two drives (both 2 TB and formatted with exFAT, both with independent power supplies), but I ran into an error.

Unfortunately I am not an expert at Linux und commands.

Here is what I've done:

- installed mdadm with apt-get install mdadm
- found both devices with `sudo fdisk -l` (as /dev/sda and /dev/sdb)
- set up RAID 1 to /dev/md0 with `sudo mdadm -Cv /dev/md0 -l1 -n2 /dev/sd[ab]1`
- formatted /dev/md0 with `sudo mkfs /dev/md0 -t ext4`
- mounted /dev/md0 to /media/nas with `sudo mount /dev/md0 /media/nas`
- edited /etc/fstab with `/dev/md0 /media/nas ext4 4 0 0`
- added AUTOSTART=true to /etc/default/mdadm
- enabled samba in /etc/samba/smb.conf

Everything went well and I could upload my files to /media/nas with WinSCP.

Now my Problem:
The next day my uploads failed with error code 4 (no further error text).
When I run `sudo fdisk -l` I found both devices sda and sdb.
Also there is /dev/md0 with size of 2000.3 GB, but there is also /dev/md127 with size 2000.3 GB.

When I run `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0` I get the following:

/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Jan  5 12:23:50 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1953371712 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953371712 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

```
Update Time : Sun Jan  7 14:37:23 2018
      State : clean, degraded
```

Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

```
       Name : raspberrypi:0  (local to host raspberrypi)
       UUID : 926bc124:2945e335:1e79ab6c:06b12095
     Events : 21

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       0        0        0      removed
   1       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1
```

The output of `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md127` is:

/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Jan  5 12:23:50 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1953371712 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953371712 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

```
Update Time : Sun Jan  7 14:38:47 2018
      State : clean, degraded
```

Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

```
       Name : raspberrypi:0  (local to host raspberrypi)
       UUID : 926bc124:2945e335:1e79ab6c:06b12095
     Events : 27

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   1       0        0        1      removed
```

When I try to set up the RAID again with `sudo mdadm -Cv /dev/md0 -l1 -n2 /dev/sd[ab]1`, I get the error:

`mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/sda1: Device or resource busy
mdadm: failed container membership check
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sda1: Device or resource busy`

How can I set the RAID up again, where does md127 come from and what causes this error?

(rebooting doesn't do anything)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you missed one important step: Create `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` _before_ rebooting (e.g. https://blog.alexellis.io/hardened-raspberry-pi-nas/#30theraidarray or https://www.stewright.me/2017/08/create-raid-volume-raspberry-pi/). As `mdadm.conf`does not describe your configuration, there will be a guess when finding raid info and the raid will be named from `md127`downwards. So just create `mdadm.conf` as described, then modify it to read `md0`instead of `md127`. After reboot it should work again.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. Since I've done this (and also set a reboot delay), I can only find md0 but like avove /dev/sda1 is active and the other drive is "removed". Don't know why. Before rebooting both drives where active.
mdadm.conf says: `ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=raspberrypi:0 UUID=97660f1c:97eabbc5:789d6f50:92703ab2`

Answer (score 0):

What happened is your RAID array fell apart.  Based on the fragmentary output you've provided, I suspect `/dev/sdb1` suffered a transient fault (most likely a hiccup of the Pi's USB system) and was marked as failed.  When it came back online, the Linux `md` subsystem saw it as a new RAID volume not belonging to any known array, and set it up as `/dev/md127`.

When you ran `sudo mdadm -Cv /dev/md0 -l1 -n2 /dev/sd[ab]1`, you got lucky: it failed.  Running `mdadm --create` is almost *never* the solution to a RAID problem.  It's far more likely to destroy your data than recover it.

At this point, your best option is probably to destroy the `/dev/md127` array and re-add `/dev/sdb1` to `/dev/md0`.

1. Make sure that `/dev/md0` really is the live copy of your data.  Inspect the output of `mount` to verify that it's mounted on `/media/nas`, and run `ls /media/nas` to make sure your data is there.
2. Remove `/dev/sdb1` from `/dev/md127`: `mdadm /dev/md127 --fail /dev/sdb1`, followed by `mdadm /dev/md127 --remove /dev/sdb1`.
3. Make `/dev/sdb1` not look like a RAID member anymore: `wipefs -a /dev/sdb1`.
4. Put it back into `/dev/md0`: `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1`.
5. Let the computer rebuild the array, copying everything from `/dev/sda1`.

To prevent this from happening in the future, set up entries describing your array in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`.  If a drive temporarily falls out of the array, `mdadm` will see it in the configuration file, and will sit there waiting for you to perform step (4).

If your setup has a habit of producing temporary failures, consider adding a write-intent bitmap to your array: `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --bitmap=internal`.  This will slow down writes somewhat, as the bitmap needs to be updated, but will greatly speed up recovery, as only the changes need to be copied from one disk to the other.  If you add a write-intent bitmap, you put temporarily-failed disks back into the array with `--re-add` rather than `--add`.